# iOS, Delay Display in UITableView with insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Tags: uitableview, nsoperationqueue

I have a custom `NSObject` class, doing some FTP work (display, transfer...).

This FTP class has a `downloadFiles:` method, which is launch inside a `NSOperationQueue`.

And I would like that method to provide some results as a data source in a `UITableView`. So I decided to delegate those results to the `UITableViewController`.

So the protocol for the FTP class :

```
@protocol FTPDelegate;
```

..

```
@interface FTP...    
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <FTPDelegate> delegate;
```

...

```
@protocol FTPDelegate
-(void)FTPMessageReceived: (NSString *)message;
@end
```

Then I declared the custom `UITableViewController` as delegate of the FTP class:

```
self.myFTP = (FTP *) [self FTPManager];

self.myFTP.delegate = self;
```

So when the downloadFiles: method from the FTP class wants to display some message in the `UITableView`, it calls:

```
[[self delegate] FTPMessageReceived:@"dir created"];
```

The `UITableViewController` implements that method :

```
-(void)FTPMessageReceived: (NSString *)message {
  NSUInteger index;
  NSArray * indexArray;
  [[self logLine] addObject: message]; // logLine is my data source
  index = [[self logLine] count]-1;
  NSLog(@"%u", index);
  indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
  [[self logView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```

The insert works, but the new row takes around 5 seconds to be displayed in the `UITableView` !!

And when I put some log inside the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, it's display immediately.

And when I put the `FTPMessageReceived` code inside a button (for example), the `UITableView` displays the new row immediately !

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `FTPMessageReceived:` is being called on a background thread.  Try calling it on the main thread with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[self delegate] FTPMessageReceived:@"dir created"];
});
```